# How to set shipping Method Programmatically if product have custom attribute

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I want to set custom shipping method programmatically if product have custom attribute in magento 2

.I am using **checkout_cart_add_product_complete** event and getting product attribute after adding in cart.

**etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
        <observer name="checkout_cart_product_add_after_add_shipping"
                  instance="Sarvesh\Tiwari\Observer\CheckoutCartProductAddAfter"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**observer/CheckoutCartProductAddAfter.php**

```
$item = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
        $itemProId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product_data = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($itemProId);
        $supplier = $product_data->getData('supplier');
        if(isset($supplier) && $supplier!=''){
            if($supplier=='supplier_a'){
                //echo 'Supplier a add Shipping Method UPS';
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setFlateRate(true);
            $quote->save();
            }elseif($supplier=='supplier_b'){
                //echo 'Supplier b add Shipping Method FedeX';
               $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
                $quote->getShippingAddress()->setFlateRate(true);
                $quote->save();
            }elseif($supplier=='supplier_b' && $supplier=='supplier_a'){
                echo 'both A && B apply both shipping Method';
            }
        }
```

how to set custom shipping method in magento 2.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, I fetch product attributes in shipping.html, and as per conditions marked shipping method.